# How to load file content to redis from kubernetes container "command"?

Tags: kubernetes, redis

I have a redis server running in kubernetes pod:
this is deployment file

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: master
      image: redis
      command:
      - redis-server
      env:
        - name: MASTER
          value: "true"
```

when i login to redis i have codes file with some strings in it:

```
# pwd
/data
# ls
codes
```

what i need is in container spec, how to load this file to redis?
so when I run a container it should execute container command and load file content to redis?

Comment: Is this your own image, or are you using the [official `redis` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis) (I ask because if you're using the official image you shouldn't be specifying `command` just to get `redis-server` running).

Comment: With respect to loading data, you could spawn a separate [`Job`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) that would be responsible for loading the data, or you might be able to do something clever with a [`postStart` command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/).

Comment: It is official redis image. So, how can I load this file when I run container? I use config map to copy file into redis container. But now I need to load it somehow during deploying of container?